# Estoy teniendo problemas con guardar los datos en una lista

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la universidad, me pidieron hacer un codigo con clases donde pueda ingresar el nombre, horas trabajadas y el sueldo de N trabajadores, luego calcular un bono dependiendo las horas trabajadas y imprimir los datos de los trabajadores justo a su bono, tengo una clase `Trabajador` donde tengo las variables de clase "nombre, horas y sueldo" con el `__init__` definiedo las variables de instancia, luego tengo otra clase `Main` en donde tengo el metodo de ingreso de los datos, en este metodo defino una lista en donde los datos se estarian guardando `lista_trab`, todo esto en un archivo, despues tengo otro archivo `Main1` donde importo todo lo del archivo con las clases, este archivo `Main1` es el que tiene el Menu donde se ingresar las opciones, 1 para ingresar datos, en esta opcion llamo al metodo de ingresar de la clase `Main`, el 2 es para imprimir la lista con los datos de los trabajadores, y aca es donde tengo mi problema, en el archivo `Main1` hice una lista `lista_trabajadores = []` para guardar los datos de la lista `lista_trab` y luego imprimir esta, esa es la operacion que no se hacer, ya que cada vez que imprimo la lista `lista_trabajadores` se imprime vacia ya que asi la defini en el archivo `Main1`, no se donde y como hacer el vinculo de las 2 listas para que cuando imprima la `lista_trabajadores` tenga los datos de la `lista_trab`... Me dijieron que el modelo de datos del codigo estaba malo pero esa no es mi preocupacion por el momento ya que me queda poco plazo para entregar el codigo, si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo sin tener que crear otra lista en el archivo `Main1` y simplemente llamar la `lista_trab`, mejor aun, pero eso tampoco lo se hacer, tambien en el archivo con las clases en el def de ingreso de datos, puse un print despues de hacer el `.append` con los datos a la `lista_trab`, pero ese print si siquiera esta corriendo...

como se abran dado cuenta soy nuevo a la programacion y si me pudieran ayudar con el codigo para que funcione correctamente se los agradeceria muchisimo, me han dado explicaciones pero todavia no entiendo bien como funciona Python. Les dejo mi codigo

Archivo con las clases

```
class Trabajador:
    nombre=""
    horas = 0
    sueldo = 0

    def __init__(self,nombre,horas,sueldo):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.horas=horas
        self.sueldo=sueldo
        pass

class Main:


    def ingreso_trabajador(lista_trab,nombre,horas,sueldo):
        Trabajador.nombre=input("Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ")
        while True:
            try:
                Trabajador.horas = float(input("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ingrese un valor numerico, intentelo nuevamente")
        while True:
            try:
                Trabajador.sueldo = int(input("Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: "))
                if (Trabajador.horas < 30):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 15 / 100) 
                    print(bono)
                    break
                elif (Trabajador.horas >= 30 and Trabajador.horas < 40):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 25 / 100)
                    print(bono)
                    break
                elif (Trabajador.horas >= 40):
                    bono=(Trabajador.sueldo * 35 / 100)
                    print (bono)
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ingrese un valor numerico entero, intentelo nuevamente")
                T=Main(Trabajador.nombre, Trabajador.horas, Trabajador.sueldo)
                lista_trab.append(T)
                opc=input("Desea ingresar otro trabajador? si/no")
                if opc=="no":
                    print(lista_trab)
                    break
```

Archivo del programa

```
from Trabajador1 import *

print("----------------------------------------------")
print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
print("1- Ingresar Trabajador")
print("2- Mostrar los datos de los trabajadores")
print("0- Salir")
lista_trabajadores=[]
while True:
    try:
        opc = int(input("Ingrese su opcion: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar una opcion valida, intentelo nuevamente")


while opc!=0:
    if opc == 1:
        while True:
            Main.ingreso_trabajador(lista_trabajadores)
            opc=input("Desea ingresar otro trabajador? si/no : ")
            if opc == "no":
                break
    
    if opc==2:
        print(lista_trabajadores) #aca solamente estoy dejando el print para ver si los 
                                       #datos se estan guardando
    
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
    print("1- Ingresar Trabajador")
    print("2- Mostrar los datos de los trabajadores")
    print("0- Salir")
    opc = int(input(">"))
```

Comment: La única parte donde actualizas la lista es cuando tienes una excepción al ingresar el sueldo. Si el usuario ingresa correctamente la cantidad, no se produce la excepción ni se ejecuta el `.append()`. Tienes varios otros problemas también, aparte de ese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay tantos errores y fallas conceptuales que no se por donde empezar. Valga este código para ilustrar el objetivo al que aspiras. Su estudio te sera de provecho.

```
class Trabajador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, horas, sueldo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.horas = horas
        self.sueldo = sueldo

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre} {self.horas} {self.sueldo}"


def ingreso_trabajador():
    #
    #   Pide datos y retorna un trabajador
    #
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: ")

    while True:
        try:
            horas = float(input("Ingrese las horas trabajadas: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Ingrese un valor numerico, intentelo nuevamente")

    while True:
        try:
            sueldo = int(input("Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: "))
            if horas < 30:
                bono = (sueldo * 15 / 100)
                break
            elif horas < 40:
                bono = sueldo * 25 / 100
                break
            else:
                bono = sueldo * 35 / 100
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Ingrese un valor numerico entero, intentelo nuevamente")
        print(bono)

    return Trabajador(nombre, horas, sueldo)

print("----------------------------------------------")
print("MENU PRINCIPAL")
print("1- Ingresar Trabajador")
print("2- Mostrar los datos de los trabajadores")
print("0- Salir")

lista_trabajadores = []

while True:
    try:
        opc = int(input("Ingrese su opcion: "))

        if opc == 0:
            break
        elif opc == 1:
            trabajador = ingreso_trabajador()
            lista_trabajadores.append(trabajador)
        elif opc == 2:
            for trabajador in lista_trabajadores:
                print(trabajador)
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar una opcion valida, intentelo nuevamente")
```

#### Demo

```
----------------------------------------------
MENU PRINCIPAL
1- Ingresar Trabajador
2- Mostrar los datos de los trabajadores
0- Salir
Ingrese su opcion: 1
Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: juan
Ingrese las horas trabajadas: 46
Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: 100
Ingrese su opcion: raul
Debe ingresar una opcion valida, intentelo nuevamente
Ingrese su opcion: 1
Ingrese el nombre del trabajador: raul
Ingrese las horas trabajadas: 54
Ingrese el sueldo del trabajador: 200
Ingrese su opcion: 2
juan 46.0 100
raul 54.0 200
Ingrese su opcion:
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! tenia una duda, que funcion cumple ```    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre} {self.horas} {self.sueldo}"``` en el codigo?? Te agradeceria mucho una explicacion, de todas formas, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: El método `__str__()` es llamado automáticamente cada vez que Python debe imprimir un objeto. El método debe retornar un string con la representación humana del objeto.. Si tienes un objeto X y haces `print(X)`, Python ejecutará `X.__str__()` y luego `print()` imprimira lo que retorna.

Comment: Notese que este método también es llamado por la función str.